# Java- not removing from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

OK so I have this HashMap

```
private Map<String, Player> players = new HashMap<String, Player>();
```

Here is what I use to remove:

```
      public void destroy() {

players.remove("Red");
os.println(me.getUsername() + "|1|has left|yes|chat");

      }
```

I say Red because it's just a TEST right now. I will get the eventual correct one later. Anyways...

I use THIS to check.

```
  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Q) {
            for (Player playert : players.values()) {
                                        c.append("\n < "+playert.getUsername() + " > ");
                        }
                    }
```

When I'm all by myself.. I press Q and I get:

```
< Dan >
```

then my friend Red logs in and I Press Q... I get:

```
< Dan >
< Red >
```

then he leaves I press Q and I get:

```
< Dan >
< Red >
```

So.. how come this isn't working?

Also, here is the code that gets called in init() when a player logs in the game (starts the applet)

```
 public void playerLogin() throws IOException {

            Random roll = new Random();
            int newNo = roll.nextInt(200);
            // me.getUsername() = "Guest #" + roll.nextInt(110);
            // String me.getUsername() = getParameter("name");

            me = new Player();
            me.setUsername(getParameter("name"));
            me.setPlayerImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("me.gif")));
            me.setX(256);
            me.setY(256);
            me.setMap(1);
            me.setCommand("move");
            players.put(me.getUsername(), me);

            repaint();

            System.out.println(me.getUsername() + " was added. player: " + me);
            os.println(me.getUsername() + "|" + me.getX() + "|" + me.getY() + "|"
                        + me.getMap() + "|" + me.getCommand());

            attack = 4;
            defense = 5;
            gold = 542;
            level = 1;
            exp = 53;

      }
```

Comment: You should also probably post your code that shows how/when you add the player to your `players` object when they log in.

Comment: And the code for where the destroy method actually gets called.

Comment: The destory method is called when a user exits the webpage that the applet is on. I edited my post to include what happens when a player logins

Comment: There is no need to "delete" your question just because it is solved.  It can be of help for someone else having a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, your [`Applet#destroy()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#destroy%28%29) method is not called at the moment you expect it is called? You should use [`Applet#stop()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#stop%28%29). The `destroy()` is only called when the object in question is eligible for GC and/or when the whole browser instance is been closed (and thus not only the current page/tab). JVM may namely keep running as long as the browser instance runs.

Comment: its getting called. but the reason it doesnt work now is because im gettigng another error. tansk

Comment: Still, you should prefer `stop()` for that. What exactly is/was the problem? Is it now solved? By the way, now I read your code once more, maybe it's the vague code, but do you realize that the applet instance isn't shared among different visitors at all?

Answer (score 1):

When you hit Q... you are checking the contents of `players` but where is your call to `destroy()`?  Do you explicitly call `destroy()` anywhere in your code?